# No resource found that matches the given name: attr android:actionModeShareDrawable even though I'm using appcompat 20

Tags: android

My app suddenly stopped compiling and is showing a bunch of errors like "No resource found that matches the given name: attr android:actionModeShareDrawable".

I'm not using appcompat 21.0.0 or the android 5 sdk as many answers on StackOverflow suggest and the same code has been compiled last friday.

The only different is that now I'm using Android Studio RC2.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION


    defaultConfig {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.8"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
    provided 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile project(':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

And here is the gradle.properties:

```
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=15
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=20
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=19
```

I'm not referencing Android 5 SDK or compatibility libs v21, so why is it bothering me about this resource keys?

Comment: I have the same problem, it happend with we when I removed a module.

Comment: try actionModeShareDrawable without android: and tell the result

Comment: I'm not setting this in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what causes it, but I had the same problem and this workaround works for me:

add

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    }
}
```

below the android{} block in your gradle file.

EDIT: This error was caused by the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library. 
The fix is to include that library in your project like this:

```
compile('com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Comment: How can I see the dependencies of my app's dependencies? I don't think I have updated my dependencies versions, but as I'm not referencing anything from Android 21 directly, the only option to find the culprit is to look at the libraries I'm using.

Comment: I also didn't reference anything from Android 21. I just included this in my build.gradle of my app module.

Comment: I've found the dependency who was causing the error, it's SlidingUpPanel from https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: Ah that explains it, I also have that library. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've set the compile instruction to use the version 2.0.2, but thanks for your help.